# How to fix the ghosting of SwifyUI List while scrolling on MacOS?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swift5

I'm using `ForEach` of `SwiftUI` on `MacOS` with transparent `NSWindow` background, it shows ghosting while scrolling, is this a bug of `SwiftUI` or a wrong usage? How can I fix it? Thank you!

[**Code is here**](https://github.com/someniceone/SwiftUIListGhosting) https://github.com/someniceone/SwiftUIListGhosting

[image: ghosting]

My Code:

```swift
struct ScriptListRow: View {

    var script: Script
    var index: Int

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(script.iconName)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
            Text(script.filename)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            Spacer()
        }
                .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                .padding(.vertical, 8)
    }
}

struct ScriptList: View {

    @State private var selectedId: Int?

    let withIndex = scripts.enumerated().map({ $0 })

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(withIndex, id: \.element.id) { index, script in
                    ScriptListRow(script: script, index: index)
                    .background(selectedId == index ? Color.accentColor : (index % 2 == 1 ? Color.clear: Color(white: 0.1, opacity: 0.2)))
                    .onTapGesture(perform: {
                        selectedId = index
                    })
                }
            }
        }
                .frame(width: .infinity, height: 300, alignment: .top)
    }
}
```

Comment: Provided code is not enough to reproduce the issue. Would you elaborate more?

Comment: @Asperi would you pls take a look at this: https://github.com/someniceone/SwiftUIListGhosting